# CSS Custom checkboxes in grid - can't remove original checkbox

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have some checkboxes in a grid and want to use vanilla-css and html to make a custom checkbox. That works fine. The problem is the remaining box of the original checkbox, that stays in my grid and makes it behave in strange ways as it takes a cell. Even when I make it transparent or deactivate it, as it is often suggested.

In the original example they moved it out of the screen area, but I can make it escape the grid.

I think this is the part where it fails to behave like I want to:

```css
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

Here is a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/3mzsLj1v/14/

Here is the example I used: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Here is the real code I work on: https://codepen.io/vaeng/pen/XWXKoMb

Thanks for your help. I am sure this is very common, but being a beginner, I might not use css in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your "minimal" and "real code" examples, your "New Checkboxes" comments are not properly opened.

In minimal example:
Line 23: `*New Checkboxes*/` s/b `/*New Checkboxes*/`

In real code example:
Line 123: `* New Checkboxes and radio buttons*/` s/b `/* New Checkboxes and radio buttons*/`

If you fix these lines, your code should work as intended.

Also, I noticed in line 102 that you put `//` before `visibility: hidden;`. If you want to comment this line, this syntax is not valid in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You see, your `label` and `input` element are on the same level, and even with `position: absolute;` your `input` still a part of the grid. Replaced your `input` inside the `label`, added `span` element and rewrited CSS.

Although in your code was

```
* New Checkboxes*/

/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

The first comment was closed incorrect, so next statement didn't work.

```css
.body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-box {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  align-self: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.inner-box {
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}


/* New Checkboxes*/


/* Base for label styling */

[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+span,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.95em;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* checkbox aspect */

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+span:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: transparent;
}


/* checked mark aspect */

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+span:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  content: '\2713\0020';
  position: absolute;
  top: .05em;
  left: .2em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* checked mark aspect changes */

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+span:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="inner-box">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="inner-box">
    <label for="box1" class="container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box1"><span>Selectbox1</span>
    </label>
    <label for="box2" class="container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box2"><span>Selectbox2</span>    
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And please, don't use `display: grid;` for every element. It's very specific setting only for cases, when you really need you use `grid`.

Comment: Interesting, I have to think about the grid thing a bit more I guess.